# Zope/Plone index rebuild fails

Tags: plone, zope

I have a Plone 4.1.3 instance with a corrupt Zope index. The instance has been upgraded several times. At some point - probably during the transition from Plone 3 to 4 - the index became corrupt. When I attempt a complete rebuild of the index the operation fails with many 'item not found' errors.

What tools are available to repair a Zope/Plone index?

Here is the traceback from the catalog rebuild:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 459, in manage_catalogRebuild
Module plone.app.discussion.patches, line 46, in patchedClearFindAndRebuild
Module OFS.FindSupport, line 239, in ZopeFindAndApply
Module OFS.FindSupport, line 239, in ZopeFindAndApply
Module OFS.FindSupport, line 239, in ZopeFindAndApply
Module OFS.FindSupport, line 239, in ZopeFindAndApply
Module OFS.FindSupport, line 227, in ZopeFindAndApply
Module plone.app.discussion.patches, line 25, in indexObject
Module Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex, line 38, in indexObject
Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 387, in catalog_object
Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 476, in catalog_object
Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 322, in catalogObject
Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 272, in updateMetadata
Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 396, in recordify
Module plone.indexer.wrapper, line 59, in __getattr__
Module plone.indexer.delegate, line 16, in __call__
Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 221, in getObjSize
Module Products.ATContentTypes.content.base, line 198, in get_size
Module plone.app.blob.field, line 273, in get_size
Module plone.app.blob.field, line 85, in get_size
Module plone.app.blob.utils, line 52, in openBlob
Module ZODB.Connection, line 860, in setstate
Module ZODB.Connection, line 922, in _setstate
Module ZODB.blob, line 644, in loadBlob
POSKeyError: 'No blob file'
```

Comment: The catalog index, you mean? How did you reindex before?

Comment: Correct, the catalog index. Now when I attempt to clear and rebuild I get a critical error after about a minute with traceback output.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add that traceback.

Comment: Before a recent upgrade I was able to clear and rebuild with no problem. I can still update the catalog successfully.

Comment: Sure, but without a traceback there isn't much I can do but make wild guesses.

Comment: The traceback indicates that the blob file directory went missing at some point, which is consistent with every failure since the problem began. I know the root cause of the problem - just wondering what tools are available to fix it.

Comment: The traceback is too long to include, but I'll provide the top lines and the end lines.Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
 
   ...
    
    Module plone.app.blob.field, line 273, in get_size
    Module plone.app.blob.field, line 85, in get_size
    Module plone.app.blob.utils, line 52, in openBlob
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 860, in setstate
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 922, in _setstate
    Module ZODB.blob, line 644, in loadBlob

POSKeyError: 'No blob file'

Comment: Edit your question; use the `{}` button to format the traceback as a codeblock.

Comment: The problem is not the index; reindexing requires asking all objects for the indexed values again; your objects themselves are broken; you r blobs are *still* missing.

Answer (score 1):

Install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/experimental.gracefulblobmissing/0.3.0 so that the ZODB won't fail on missing blob files.

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like this is a patch to permit Plone to gracefully omit blob files that aren't there. My issue is a little different. I can't rebuild the catalog index. I really nead something that will help me repair the catalog index.

Comment: but you can't rebuild because of a missing blob files, as the tracebask says :)